# SetDelayed::wrsym on first use of \[FormalX] in Plot & ContourPlot

Tags: bugs, symbols

**Bug introduced in 11.1 or earlier and persisting through 11.3.0 or later**

CASE:4024964

---

Here's a weird one.  Starting with a fresh kernel, the first time I plot a function of `\[FormalX]`, I get an error and a blank graph:

```
Plot[\[FormalX], {\[FormalX], 0, 1}]
(* SetDelayed::wrsym: Symbol \[FormalX] is Protected. *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then if I rerun the same code, it works fine:

```
Plot[\[FormalX], {\[FormalX], 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I've tried a few other formal variables.  Plotting with `\[FormalY]` and `\[FormalZ]` both work from the start, and even prevent the same error with `\[FormalX]` when used afterwards.

Does anyone else have this problem?  I'm using Mathematica 11.2 on MacOS 10.13.3.  Any idea what the cause is?

**Addendum (June 3, 2018)**

I've run into the same problem with `ContourPlot`.  As per Szabolcs' comment, I had fixed my problem with `Plot` by placing `Plot[0, {x, 0, 1}];` at the top of the package I'm writing to be silently run when loaded.  However this does not prevent the same error from occuring with `ContourPlot`.  However, adding `ContourPlot[0,{x,0,1},{y,0,1}];` does fix it.

Comment: I can reproduce this behavior with V11.1.1 running of OS X 10.10.5. Certainly looks like a bug to me.

Comment: I can reproduce the error on 11.2.0 for Mac OS X 10.13.3 on a fresh kernel.

Comment: Related: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43189163#43189163, https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43201818#43201818

Comment: @MichaelE2 Huh, that's a weird coincidence!

Comment: As mentioned in the chat, I can reproduce this as well. I reported this to the beta team because I too believe it should work and it seems to be a specific case that slipped through.

Comment: Yep. I agree it's a bug.  Executing almost any(?) plot command seems to fix it. It makes me wonder what they mean in the docs that formal symbols are "Used to represent a formal parameter that will never be assigned a value" -- except in `Plot`, `Table`, `Do`, etc.  (These functions can set a value to protected symbol, even a locked one; `Block` cannot if the symbol is locked, though.

Comment: There is no such bug in version 8.0.4 on Win-x64. Can someone look into versions 9 and 10?

Comment: This seems to be a Mac problem; I can't reproduce this on Linux.

Comment: @J.M. Which version are you running? I can reproduce it on Linux with 11.2

Comment: @MichaelE2 Interesting observation that `Plot` can set a value even for a `Locked` symbol (but not `Block`).  It could be that they use ``Internal`LocalizedBlock``, as it seems to be able to do this as well.  I was under the impression that the purpose of `LocalizedBlock` was to localize compound expressions such as `a[1]` (instead of `a`).  These do work in `Table`, `Plot`, etc.

Comment: @halirutan, I tried in 10.4. I'll try in 11.2 later.

Comment: My suspicion is that when `Plot` runs for the first time, it triggers the auto-loading of the same file that sets FormalX to be Protected.  Evaluating `Plot` alone is not enough to trigger it.  It is necessary to use proper syntax, e.g. `Plot[x,{x,0,1}]`. Thus it is not the loading of the `Plot` symbol itself that triggers this.  It's something else used internally by `Plot`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll expand a bit on the comments by [@Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12/szabolcs) which are essentially correct.

Various functionality implemented in top-level is typically autoloaded on first use from MX files (written by [`DumpSave`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DumpSave.html)). A feature of MX files is that when they are read back, all definitions and attributes of the saved symbols are restored.

The actual bug is caused by the `DataWrappers.mx` file unintentionally capturing the [`\[FormalX]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/FormalX.html) symbol's [`Protected`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Protected.html) attribute (the symbol itself is normally defined in a different place).

When [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) is first used, its internal dependency on [`EventData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EventData.html) triggers autoloading of `DataWrappers.mx` which causes [`\[FormalX]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/FormalX.html) to become [`Protected`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Protected.html) again, even though its attributes have been temporarily unset by localizing.

As an illustration (using [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html) instead of `` Internal`LocalizedBlock `` for simplicity):

```
Block[{\[FormalX]}, {Attributes[\[FormalX]], \[FormalX] = 1}]

(* {{}, 1} *)

Block[{\[FormalX]}, EventData; {Attributes[\[FormalX]], \[FormalX] = 1}]
```

> Set::wrsym: Symbol \[FormalX] is Protected.

```
(* {{Protected}, 1} *)

Block[{\[FormalX]}, EventData; {Attributes[\[FormalX]], \[FormalX] = 1}]

(* {{}, 1} *)
```

Note there was no longer a message on the second evaluation of the same input; that is because autoloading happens only once, at the first evaluation of [`EventData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EventData.html) in a kernel session.